# react-native ios app webview plays video but without audio

Tags: audio, uiwebview, react-native

I am using the following code to play a youtube or vimeo video via WebView on my Iphone 5S:

```
<WebView ref='webview' javaScriptEnabled={true} scrollEnabled={true} automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false} style={itemStyles.webView} url={videoUrl} onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={false} startInLoadingState={false} allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true} scalesPageToFit={false} />
```

The webview component displays the video correctly but unfortunately it is silent, it has no audio.

How can I enable audio for the webview component?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Ok sorry found the answer myself:

What I needed to do was to place a piece of code in my AppDelegate.m file:

First import the AVFoundation library:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

Then, insert the following code inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
  NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
  [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                      error:&setCategoryError];
```

and it will be ok.